# Want to add data to a form, form is valid, but data not among cleaned_data

Tags: django

**Django 1.10**

I'm trying to add data to a form programmatically.

```
class Wiki(models.Model):
    related_model = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default="")
    related_object_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default="")
    article = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False, default="")


class WikiCreate(CreateView):
    model = Wiki
    fields = ['article']

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        related_model = kwargs.get('model')
        related_object_id = kwargs.get('pk')

        form = self.get_form()
        form.data._mutable = True
        form.data['related_model'] = related_model
        form.data['related_object_id'] = related_object_id
        form.data._mutable = False

        return super(WikiCreate, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In the post method of the superclass I place a breakpoint:

```
class ProcessFormView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance with the passed
        POST variables and then checked for validity.
        """
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid(): # breakpoint
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Well, what can I see at the breakpoint.
form.data =

Then step in the debugger. form.is_valid() returns true. So, now I can see that: 1) _errors is empty; 2) cleaned_data = {'article': "Some text I've just input."}.

Well, 'related_model' and 'related_object_id' have not appeared in the cleaned data.

Could you help me understand why data from these fields are not saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't the way to add data to a form submission. You should be adding it to the model instance, not the form, once that has been created in the `form_valid` method. You shouldn't be overriding `post` at all.

```
class WikiCreate(CreateView):
    model = Wiki
    fields = ['article']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        related_model = self.kwargs.get('model')
        related_object_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        item = form.save(commit=False)
        item.related_model = related_model
        item.object_id = related_object_id
        item.save()
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you only have the fields:

`fields = ['article']`

So there are no other fields on your form other than article.  Try adding the other two fields to the fields array.  If you want them to be there, but not visible you need to create a custom form and set them to have the hidden widget